# Why does VS2013 put white text on dark highlight when printing source code?

Tags: pdf, printing, visual-studio-2013

When printing to PDF from Visual Studio, all my `.cs` files get printed with black text on white background. On the other hand, the `.css` and `.cshtml` files get printed with white text on a black highlight. The first mode is usable while the latter isn't. However, both cases seem to ignore the `Tools > Options > Environment > Fonts and Colors > Printer` configuration, which is configured to colour syntax normally on printing and has no configuration whatsoever especifying a black highlight.

On the physycal side we have an even stranger output: when physically printing on a black-and-white laser printer we got a black text on white back (result is displayed on the right-hand side of the picture below). When printing on a colour laser printer we got a white text on black highlight (on the left-hand side of the picture).

- Changing the Visual Studio Theme from Dark to Light has no effect
- Using a third party tool such as [VSCodePrint](http://starprint2000.com/product_vscodeprint.aspx) also prints the code with a black highlight
- I have used both Adobe Acrobat Pro PDF printer and CutePDF Writer, but both give me the same results as the left-hand side of the picture in the PDF (digitally, of course)

Any contribution is welcome as there is little to no information on the Web about this.

[image: picture]

Answer (score 0):

According to visual studio editor team, it was a confirmed bug on 2012.  There appeared to be a resolution (kb download) to fix that, but I don't see it being "applyable" to VS2013.  See: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/760291/vs2012-with-dark-theme-prints-code-with-black-background

Comment: So maybe it should be a known bug on VS2013 as well? :)

Comment: I can't say, but As you know they did a MAD amount of other changes on VS2013 (and it's underlying technologies) over the last year, so I think it is quite possible such a fix would have been left out.

Comment: I'll wait and see if anyone has any other input regarding VS*2013* and, if not, I'll accept your answer as the only viable.

Comment: Cool, no problem. For now, "copy paste notepad print" :)

Comment: hahahah can't exactly do that for more than a thousand files, specially cause formatting is lost in the process. Sadly.

Comment: @marquito: For the love of all the trees, please don't print a thousand *code* files.

Comment: Here comes the tree argument. =P I'm trying to print them to PDF for code licensing. Up until some time ago they had to be physically printed, but not anymore, in Brazil. :)

Comment: @marquito is virtually saving thousands of trees :)